# How to use awk variables in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file called **domain** which contains some domains. For example:

```
google.com
facebook.com
...
yahoo.com
```

And I have another file called **site** which contains some sites URLs and numbers. For example:

```
image.google.com   10
map.google.com     8
...
photo.facebook.com  22
game.facebook.com   15
..
```

Now I'm going to count the url number each domain has. For example: **google.com** has **10+8**. So I wrote an awk script like this:

```
BEGIN{
  while(getline dom < "./domain" > 0) {
    domain[dom]=0;
  }
  for(dom in domain) {
    while(getline < "./site" > 0) {
      if($1 ~/$dom$)   #if $1 end with $dom {
        domain[dom]+=$2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the code `if($1 ~/$dom$)` doesn't run like I want. Because the variable $dom in the regular expression was explained literally. So, the first question is:

**Is there any way to use variable `$dom` in a regular expression?**

Then, as I'm new to writing script

**Is there any better way to solve the problem I have?**

Answer (score 56):

`awk` can match against a variable if you don't use the `//` regex markers.

`if ( $0 ~ regex ){ print $0; }`

In this case, build up the required regex as a string

```
regex = dom"$"
```

Then match against the `regex` variable

```
if ( $1 ~ regex ) {
  domain[dom]+=$2;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

First of all, the variable is `dom` not `$dom` -- consider `$` as an operator to extract the value of the column number stored in the variable `dom`

Secondly, awk will not interpolate what's between `//` -- that is just a string in there.

You want the `match()` function where the 2nd argument can be a string that is treated as the regular expression:

```
if (match($1, dom "$")) {...}
```

I would code a solution like:

```
awk '
  FNR == NR {domain[$1] = 0; next}
  {
    for (dom in domain) {
      if (match($1, dom "$")) {
        domain[dom] += $2
        break
      }
    }
  }
  END {for (dom in domain) {print dom, domain[dom]}}
' domain site
```

Comment: Apropos all those talking about how variables are not prefixed with $, it's better explained (IMO) as $ means field in awk, so $dom would mean field whatever the value of dom is.

Variables in awk are used unquoted and without $.  It's not shell!

Answer (score 2):

One way using an `awk` script:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "[. ]"
    OFS = "."
}

FNR == NR {
    domain[$1] = $0
    next
}

FNR < NR {
    if ($2 in domain) {
        for ( i = 2; i < NF; i++ ) {
            if ($i != "") {
                line = (line ? line OFS : "") $i
            }
        }
        total[line] += $NF
        line = ""
    }
}

END {
    for (i in total) {
        printf "%s\t%s\n", i, total[i]
    }
}
```

Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk domain.txt site.txt
```

Results:

```
facebook.com    37
google.com  18
```

Comment: This approach is not going to work if you get a domain like "first.second.example.com" in the `site` file.

Comment: @glennjackman, yes you are correct. I did not consider that :-(

Answer (score 1):

You clearly want to read the `site` file once, not once per entry in `domain`.  Fixing that, though, is trivial.

Equally, variables in `awk` (other than fields `$0` .. `$9`, etc) are not prefixed with `$`.  In particular, `$dom` is the field number identified by the variable `dom` (typically, that's going to be `0` since domain strings don't convert to any other number).

I think you need to find a way to get the domain from the data read from the `site` file.  I'm not sure if you need to deal with sites with country domains such as `bbc.co.uk` as well as sites in the GTLDs (`google.com` etc).  Assuming you are not dealing with country domains, you can use this:

```
BEGIN {
    while (getline dom < "./domain" > 0) domain[dom] = 0
    FS = "[ .]+"
    while (getline  < "./site" > 0)
    {
        topdom = $(NF-2) "." $(NF-1)
        domain[topdom] += $NF          
    }
    for (dom in domain) print dom "  " domain[dom]
}
```

In the second `while` loop, there are `NF` fields; `$NF` contains the count, and `$1` .. `$(NF-1)` contain components of the domain.  So, `topdom` ends up containing the top domain name, which is then used to index into the array initialized in the first loop.

Given the data in the question (minus the lines of dots), the output is:

```
yahoo.com  0
facebook.com  37
google.com  18
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the answers above is that you cannot use the "metacharacters" (e.g. \< for a word boundary at the beginning of a word) if you use a string instead of a regular expression /.../.
If you had a domain xyz.com and two sites ab.xyz.com and cd.prefix_xyz.com, the numbers of the two site entries would be added to xyz.com

Here's a solution using awk's pipe and the sed command:
...

```
for(dom in domain) {
    while(getline < "./site" > 0) {
        # let sed replaces occurence of the domain at the end of the site
        cmd = "echo '" $1 "' | sed 's/\\<'" dom "'$/NO_VALID_DOM/'"
        cmd | getline x
        close(cmd)
        if (match(x, "NO_VALID_DOM")) { 
          domain[dom]+=$2;
        }
    }
    close("./site") # this misses in original code
}
```

...