# One awk script bug i can't fix

Tags: awk

I have two file.
**domain.txt** contains some domains

```
facebook.com
google.com
yahoo.com
```

**site.txt** contains some sites under the domains, and their URL number.

```
music.google.com  2
image.google.com  3
music.facebook.com  8
image.facebook.com  4
map.yahoo.com   4
new.yahoo.com   7
```

I'm going to select the sites, which's URL number is bigger than the average URL number it's domain have. For example, the average URL number of **google.com** is **(2+3)/2=2.5**, so the **image.google.com** will be picked.

I wrote awk script like this:

```
BEGIN {
        #read all domains into memory
        while(getline dom < "./domain.txt" > 0){
                domain[dom]=0;
        }

        #count URLs number and sites number under each domain
        for (dom in domain){
                sitenumber=0;

                close("./site.txt")
                while(getline < "./site.txt" >0){
                        if(match($1,"."dom"$")){
                                domain[dom]+=$2;
                                sitenumber++;
                                printf("%s\n",$0) >> "./sitesunderdomain";
                        } 
                }

                avgsitenumber = domain[dom]/sitenumber;
                system("cat ./sitesunderdomain") #test output

                close("./sitesunderdomain")
                while(getline < "./sitesunderdomain" >0){ #loop A
                        print "why1" #test output
                        if($2>=avgsitenumber){
                                print "why2"  #testoutput
                                print $0,avgsitenumber>>"./result"
                        }
                }
                system("> ./sitesunderdomain")
        }#for
}
```

then I run the awk script in the bash, get the output:

```
music.facebook.com  8
image.facebook.com 4
why1
why2
why1
music.google.com   2
image.google.com  3
map.yahoo.com  4
news.yahoo.com  7
```

And the **./result** was

```
music.facebook.com  8  6
```

But as I expect, the output should be

```
music.facebook.com  8
image.facebook.com 4
why1
why2
why1
music.google.com   2
image.google.com  3
why1
why2
why1
map.yahoo.com  4
news.yahoo.com  7
why1
why2
why1
```

And the **./result** should be:

```
music.facebook.com  8  6
image.google.com  3  2.5
news.yahoo.com  7  5.5
```

It seems like at `loop A` position, `getline` return `0` when `dom` was **google.com** and **yahoo.com**.
**Why?**

Comment: You'll probably want to escape the `.` in the match; it matches any character as it stands.  Either `"\."` (unless that needs to be `"\\."`) or `"[.]"`; I'd use the latter as it doesn't raise awkward questions about the number of backslashes to use.  This is tangential to your main problem, though.

Comment: When trying to debug unexpected outputs, one of the first steps is to echo the inputs -- so you can be sure that you're getting what you expect.  You probably need to show the data files you're working with, too; I remember the general context from y'day's question (my time; earlier today in UTC), but others won't have that information available.  Besides, you should probably show what you are expecting as output.  Also, I'm not convinced that filtering stuff out to disk like that is good `awk` style.  Use arrays to hold data, not files.

Comment: See also [How to use awk variables in regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534173/how-to-use-awk-variables-in-regular-expressions/).  It's a separate question, but has the same general context.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: isn't the `\.` recommendation a bit of a red herring? This awk script is too far gone already, don't you think?

Comment: @Graham: it is pretty bad, and the mishandled metacharacter is amongst the least of its problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a mess. That is not the way to work with `awk`. `Awk` automatically opens and reads your files line by line for you, it's not jour job using `getline`. That is for special cases only.

*First* of all:

```
close("./site.txt")
while(getline < "./site-test" >0){
```

`./site-test`? Your file is `test.txt`. It died in my test.

*Second*: There is no need to create files when you can reuse data directly from RAM, like with arrays.

*Third*: I don't like your code at all, but to fix it, close your `./sitesunderdomain` temp file between reading it with `getline` and the deletion in `system("> ./sitesunderdomain")`, like:

```
## NOT here.
##close("./sitesunderdomain")

while(getline < "./sitesunderdomain" >0){ #loop A
        print "why1" #test output
        if($2>=avgsitenumber){
                print "why2"  #testoutput
                print $0,avgsitenumber>>"./result"
        }
}

## Better here between the read and the write.
close("./sitesunderdomain")

system("> ./sitesunderdomain")
```

Now run the script like:

```
awk -f myscript.awk domain.txt site.txt
```

And check output:

```
cat result
```

With following result:

```
music.facebook.com  8 6
image.google.com  3 2.5
new.yahoo.com   7 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding your script.  There's no need to manually open files like that; awk takes care of that by itself.  If your code can be fixed, I'm not the one to do it.

Here's what I came up with instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
  domain=$1; sub(/^[a-z]*\./, "", domain);
  mean[domain]=(mean[domain]*count[domain]+$2)/++count[domain];
  score[$1]=$2;
}

END {
  printf("%7s\t%6s\t%s\n", "score", "mean", "domain");
  for (hostname in score) {
    domain=hostname; sub(/^[a-z]*\./, "", domain);
    if (score[hostname] > mean[domain]) {
      printf("%6d\t%6.2f\t%s\n", score[hostname], mean[domain], hostname);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it against your data, I get the following results:

```
  score   mean  domain
     3    2.50  image.google.com
     8    6.00  music.facebook.com
     7    5.50  new.yahoo.com
```

Is that the output you're expecting?

Comment: I love your one-line "average" calculation.  :-)