# awk print lines between 2 patterns - patterns passed as variables

Tags: unix, awk

I want to print all the lines between line that contains "ABC" and an empty line.

```
awk '/ABC/,/^$/' file
```

This works fine

I want to put ABC in to a variable.So I pass it to awk as follows

```
awk -v targetLine='ABC' '/targetLine/,/^$/' file
```

This doesnt return me anything.

Can someone help whats wrong in here, why my variable is not getting picked up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use awk variables in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534173/how-to-use-awk-variables-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: You meant this line "Secondly, awk will not interpolate what's between // -- that is just a string in there" ?

Answer (score 1):

An awk program is composed of pairs of

```
 pattern { action }
```

where `action` is executed when `pattern` creates a non-zero/non-empty value. One of the possible patterns is a *pattern range*. A pattern-range is nothing more then two patterns which are comma separated.

```
pattern1 , pattern2 { action }
```

While most people write it down using ERE tokens such as:

```
/foo/,/bar/ { action }
```

the patterns can be anything which represents a valid pattern, other examples could be:

```
(FNR==3),$0=="foo" {action}  or (index($2,"foo")>2),(FNR%5==4) {action}
```

So based on this, we can just answer your question as:

```
awk -v ere="ABC" '($0 ~ ere),/^$/'
```

However, be aware that from the moment you want to slightly change your code, using pattern-ranges, you generally have to do a full rewrite (See  [Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk)): So it might be better just to write:

```
awk -v ere="ABC" '($0 ~ ere){f=1};f;/^$/{f=0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to pass the variable in AWK  without using the '-v' option:

```
var="ABC"
awk '/'"$var"'/,/^$/' file
```

And with '-v' option:

```
var="ABC"
awk -v a=$var '$0 == a,/^$/' file
```